# Count search dynamic region

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic-function

I'd like to insert a count search function into a cell and make it dynamic using VBA.

[image]

In the cell G2 I want to insert the following formula: =COUNT(SEARCH(($F$2:$F$3;B2))=0 so that it returns a true or false value. As the Table in cell A1 and the column F are liable to change I need to create a code that would insert a dynamic count search function in there.

This is the code I've inserted and I've tried to highlight the code from cell F2 and below but it doesn't seem to work.

`ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=COUNT(SEARCH(Range."F2".Currentregion,RC[-5]))=0"`

Anyone know how I can edit the code so that it looks looks up the region below F2 dynamically and creates an absolute value and also creqtes B2 a relative reference (appears to be currently RC[-5] in the code ?

Thanks,

Comment: You're  conflating VBA and formulas. Something like `Range("F2").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)` should be concatenated with the formula string, using `&`.

Comment: I am completely lost on what you are asking for. Maybe a good idea to describe what you end result should look like based on the data you have given?

Comment: Could you share what the results in `G2` and `G3` should be and how they are calculated? Please do describe it in detail because I don't understand what a *count/search formula* is.